# Java version of OCaml underscore

Tags: java, syntax, ocaml

If I'm testing something like

```
Corrector c = new FileCorrector("fileNotFound.txt");
```

and I know that this code will fail, and thus `c` will never be used, is there a way I can write this code with something like the OCaml `_` symbol?

```
Corrector _ = new FileCorrector("fileNotFound.txt");
```

Comment: No need to declare any variables. The underscore in Ocaml is a pattern, not the name of a declared variable, so they work differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

why not just not give a variable name?

```
new FileCorrector("fileNotFound.txt");
```

It looks odd because constructors really shouldn't have side-effects. But they can throw, and they literally can have side effects, so it's not that this code doesn't do anything. And as far as Eclipse warnings are concerned, this is preferred to an unused variable.